# Node UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning when calling a function

Tags: node.js, express

```
verify = function (req) { 
return new Promise(function (resolve) {

    readData(req).then(function (user_data) {
        return checkUserInfo(user_data);
    }).then(function (result) {
        return check(result)
    }).then(function (result) {
        resolve(result);
    });

});

}

function readData(req) {

return (req.body);

}
```

when i called the function verify () it shows an error in readData().

On the console I'm getting an 'UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning'

Comment: Avoid the explicit Promise construction antipattern, just return the Promise chain, and handle the error in the consumer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is in your readData() function. Try to return a promise from your readData() function. This solution will solve your problem.

```
function readData(req) {

return new Promise(function (resolve) {

    resolve(req.body);

})

}
```